# Form Authentication - Active Directory - SQL server access

Tags: active-directory, database-connection, formsauthentication

I have a web site which uses forms authentication and the user is authenticated against active directory. The user gets authenticated successfully against ad but I got exception login failed for user "" when the application tries to perform database operation. Please let me know what could be possible cause for this and what could be the solution.

Comment: What does your database connection string look like (credentials obfuscated, obviously).

Comment: No. I have set the integrated security = SSPI. I am not passing any username and password.

Answer (score 0):

I always forget this one, but be careful.  SSPI and Trusted Connection are not really the same.  With trusted, you use the auth as is, whereas SSPI you are then sending the username and password:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

vs.

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```